# Serializing and unserializing an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, tag-it

I'm using the tag-it library for jquery to make a tagging system (a bit like the stackoverflow one).

After the user types his tags the library returns a javascript array that I want to save in a MySQL database. I didn't find a serialize and unserialize function in javascript.

Before coding my own function I'd like to make sure I'm not reinventing the wheel here. It seems crazy that there is no native way to save an array to a database and then use it again.

tl;dr => how can I save a javascript array in a MySQL database to reuse it later ?

Comment: How about JSON?  It depends on how you want to save it; do you really want a single row in the database for all the tags, or do you want separate rows?  Seems like it'd be much easier to search by tag if the tags were separated into distinct rows.

Comment: It seems to be the best way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: OK, well like I said, searching by tag is going to be much, much slower if the query has to dig through a string of tags stuffed into a single column.

Comment: Problem is I want a dynamic number of tags, so I can't use separate rows since a crazy user could want 30 tags for one entry.

Comment: ??? Just have a table with a column for the primary key and a column for the tag. Then you can have as many tags as you want. That's a pretty common database pattern.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can use `JSON.stringify()` ([MDN docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)) and `JSON.parse()` ([MDN docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)) for converting a JavaScript object into a string representation to store it inside a database.

```
var arr = [ 1, 2, 3 ];

var serializedArr = JSON.stringify( arr );
// "[1, 2, 3]"

var unpackArr = JSON.parse( serializedArr );
// identical array to arr
```

If your backend is written in PHP, there are similar methods to work with JSON strings there: `json_encode()` ([PHP docu](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)) and `json_decode()` ([PHP docu](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)).

Most other languages offer similar functionalities for JSON strings.

Comment: I just want to point out that JSON.parse will clean up the serialized output from a Web Api call that uses Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject. In my case, I had a serialized string that looked like  "["Industry","Region","Topic","Type"]", and JSON.parse converted it into the desired array of strings.

Comment: This is Simple and Precise Solution :D

Answer (score 8):

You can use `JavaScript Object Notation`(`JSON`) format.

`Javascript` supports these methods:

- [**JSON.stringify**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) -> *serializes object to string*
- [**JSON.parse**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)    -> *deserializes object from string*

Answer (score 5):

How about just [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JSON)ing it?

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
var arrSerialized = JSON.stringify(arr);
...

var arrExtracted = JSON.parse(arrSerialized);
```

By the way, JSON is often used for serializing in some other languages, even though they have their own serializing functions. )